# Cannot Present View Controller From App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I need to present view controller from App Delegate I did it by the following code:

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Application Shows Black Screen. How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify. Is your goal to present this new view controller over the existing root view controller or do you wish this view controller to be the root controller? Is this `MyViewController` all done in code or is it from a storyboard or xib?

Comment: I am guessing that `rootViewController` is currently nil as well (given the black screen)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set RootViewController of window as :

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

[self.window setRootViewController:controller];
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear from the question but the goal may be to present this new view controller over the current root view controller.

Comment: Yes. I am not sure from the question but I assume needs to set MyViewController as rootviewcontroller of window directly.

Comment: And how do you know this?